# Reading XML from an Existing Non-XML File

Tags: python, xml

I have a non-XML file in which I would like to add an XML section to it. The file is created by another application, and I want to create and append an xml section to it (in the middle of the file). Then, I need to be able to read the xml section as a normal xml. I am not sure if this is possible.

The code is written in python.

```
settings = XmlReaderSettings()
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore

reader = XmlReader.Create(DXFfile, settings)

while reader.Read():
    if reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element:
        if reader.Name=="NAME":
            reader.Read()
            plog(reader.Value + "\n");
```

This is giving me the following error as soon as I run it:

> XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 3.

Here is the xml portion of the edited file:

```
  0
EMPORT
  999
<PORTLIST><HPORT><NAME>PORT TEST</NAME></HPORT></PORTLIST>
  0
SEQEND
```

Comment: Don't use an XmlReader until you're already sure that you're reading XML content. If nothing else will start with a `<`, then use that information.

Comment: I'd also strongly suggest using a more modern XML library -- `lxml.etree`, or ElementTree if sticking to the standard library, etc. Either of those will make `tostring()` and `fromstring()` operations trivial.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Where can I find documentation for those libraries? I have wanted to change the library for a while, but I am traditionally a C++ coder, so I do not have a lot of experience in Python.

Comment: http://lxml.de/ for lxml, https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html for ElementTree.

Comment: BTW, you talk about "adding XML" in the title, but I don't see any of your code in your question trying to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using [lxml](http://lxml.de/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import lxml.etree as etree
import sys

input_filename = sys.argv[1]
output_filename = sys.argv[2]

output_file = open(output_filename, 'w')
for line in open(input_filename, 'r').readlines():
  line = line.rstrip('\n')
  handled = False
  if line and line[0] == '<':
    try:
      xml_el = etree.fromstring(line)
      name = xml_el.find('.//NAME')
      if name is not None:
        print 'Found name:', name.text
      # Add a new XML element under HPORT, and print
      hport_el = xml_el.find('.//HPORT')
      if hport_el is not None:
        new_el = etree.SubElement(hport_el, 'NewElement')
        new_el.text = 'Content Here'
        print >>output_file, etree.tostring(xml_el)
        handled = True
    except lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError:
      pass # this line wasn't a valid standalone XML document
  if not handled:
    print >>output_file, line
```

Important things to note:

- We're reading and writing with standard, line-per-line I/O.
- If what we read was an XML document, we use `lxml.etree.fromstring()` to deserialize it to DOM objects, `lxml.etree.Element.find()` to find an element we want to query within it, and `lxml.etree.SubElement()` to update what we read in-place (adding a new element, in this case). If you wanted to change contents of an existing element, rather than adding a new one, you could trivially do this too.
- Once we've updated the document, we use `lxml.etree.tostring()` to convert it back to a string.

---

Running

```
./update-xml-subsections input-file output-file
```

...with your given input file will emit an output file containing:

```
  0
EMPORT
  999
<PORTLIST><HPORT><NAME>PORT TEST</NAME><NewElement>Content Here</NewElement></HPORT></PORTLIST>
  0
SEQEND
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. I am trying to understand how I would do this with the built-in xml.etree library.

Comment: I was able to get it working using the xml.etree library. Apparently there is absolutely not difference in the code.

Comment: Indeed, they're very similar. `lxml.etree` is faster, and has extra functionality, but I didn't use any of that extra functionality here.